# Where do I find the right version?

Tags: system-installation, windows

I'm using Windows 10 and I need to download Ubuntu 12.04 for a class. Is this possible?

I have tried downloading the 16.04, but It seems my system does not meet the CPU requirement of 16.04.

Comment: Please reformulate your question. As it is it doesn't make sense. CPU capabilities have nothing to do with the ability to download a file, any file... And if your running Windows 10 then certainly your machine is more than capable of running 16'04. As a matter of fact, your hardware may well be new enough as to recommend the newest release and strongly suggest a 4 years old release may not work.

Comment: I downloaded the 16 version and then tried to run it through Virtual Box and it gave me this error message " this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU"

Comment: @SarahTiemeyer There are two Ubuntu 16.04 versions, one for 32 bit processors another for 64 bit processors. It sounds like you need to download the 64 bit version.

Comment: What is your computer make and model?

Comment: I did download the 64 bit version. My computer is a HP 23-Q110

Comment: I'm trying to run it using VirtualBox and I still get the same error message

Comment: Use the 32-bit version then.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can take a look on alternative downloads in ubuntu official website where you will find the older or other versions. [Click here to see.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Comment: End of life releases should NOT be used under no circumstance and are not supported here.

Comment: She asked for the specific version and it could be his preference , I only just posted the link to that official ubuntu pages. There all 12.04 is listed along with 16.04. So what is the issue in pointing it over here ?  Ubuntu is free and opensource so why this restriction in posting it here ?

Comment: No restriction and I wasn't criticizing your answer. I just added the warning you should have included, IMO.

Comment: The answer may be premature until we find out if she downloaded 16.04 correctly. ie Her question assumes she needs an older version but she may not.

Comment: I answered above.. I'm so lost, let me know if you need any other info. I'm just trying to get this to run in a VM

Comment: @CelticWarrior you may wish to check http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life as 12.04 is supported until April of 2017

Comment: @Elder Geek - I know 12.04 is still supported. The answer, however, included a link to other old releases - "Past releases and other flavours" -, in which many are now unsupported, hence my warning comment. I didn't expect it to be so hard to understand or requiring so much explanations.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Interesting. when I check the page linked I only see LTS versions 12.04 through 16.04

Comment: @Elder Geek - Actually there's more... Just following the link "Past releases and other flavours" you already get Vivid as well (I cannot think of a areason for it being there but it is). Then, drilling down a little you also find http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ with everything there ever was. Newbies often don't know what is and what isn't supported hence my warning.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Point taken (although the OP didn't link that page. I wouldn't have either)